# Unable to append the object creation while loop for the JSON format

Tags: json, object

I am unable to append the result object to existing one, Can anyone pls help me here

Here is my data

```
    var data = [];
data.push("result");
while(inc.next()){
    data.push({
        "short_description": inc.getValue('short_description'),
        "description": inc.getValue('description')
    })
}
```

The result was coming as below JSON format

```
["result",{"short_description":"Unable to access team file share","description":"I can access my personal folder but can't access my team's folder on our file share."},{"short_description":"Employee payroll application server is down.","description":"Employee payroll application server is down.Not able to login with valid credentials."}]
```

But i was expecting as below

```
{"result": [{"short_description":"Unable to access team file share","description":"I can access my personal folder but can't access my team's folder on our file share."},{"short_description":"Employee payroll application server is down.","description":"Employee payroll application server is down.Not able to login with valid credentials."}]}
```

Comment: You forgot to mention the programming language you are using? I would assume it's JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
var data = {"result": []}; // Initialize data as an object with a "result" key

while (inc.next()) {
    // Push each object to the "result" array
    data["result"].push({
        "short_description": inc.getValue('short_description'),
        "description": inc.getValue('description')
    });
}
```